# AppFramework - using panels from separate files

Tags: appframework

I am checking out AF/AFUI/XDK and all is well, I just need some advice on how to structure my app - I have a main 'content' div and my panels live within that, to change my page area I use eg. href="#newdivname" and the new panel is loaded, great, as long as all panels are in the same page/file.

How could I achieve this with having code for different panels defined in different physical html files? This makes sense to me just so I don't have one massive unwieldy file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main index.html, you can specify your panel with `data-defer` attribute like this:

```
<div class="panel" id="panel2" data-defer="panel2.html"></div>
```

This will load contents of `panel2.html` within the `panel2`

More info here: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_panels